# System V exception on local WordPress install

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error message showing up in my WP admin for my local install:

```
Background Queue: System V exception - sem_get not available on this installation of PHP
```

I'm not an advanced PHP coder so I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Environment:
 Max OS 10.8.5
 MAMP 2.1.3
 PHP 5.4.10
 WordPress 3.6.1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056316

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is:

1. Look up [`sem_get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-get.php).
2. Click on [the main extension on the left (Semaphore)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php).
3. Read up on it's [requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.requirements.php) (none in this case), and [installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php)
4. Depending on how you installed the package, there may be pre-compiled options available for your OS which would not require you to build PHP by hand.

Comment: Is there a way to install --enable-sysvsem without recompiling PHP?

Comment: [this question did not get any answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056316/enable-php-semaphore-functions-on-mamp), so... I doubt it (don't have a Mac though, so no way to find out). The only thing I can find [is this](http://jonathonhill.net/2012-11-29/roll-your-own-mamp-development-environment/), which _does_ require you to compile.

Comment: Another option would be to try the prepackaged [ZendServer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads). it has a Mac download at least...

Comment: I came across the post also, which looks like the way to go.  I'll give it a try when I have a chance.  I can live with the error message for a while.  Thanks for your help!